# C# Nested foreach loop - CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach, nested

I have a two checkBoxLists, one is called CheckBoxList1 (3 Items, lets call them A, B, AND C) and the other is CheckBoxList2 (Contains 2 items lets call them 1 and 2).

I insert the values that have been selected from checkboxlist1 and checkboxlist2 to the database into two columns, however I am running into this issue: When I select for example A and B then 1 and 2 this is the values that get imported to the database:

```
column1  column2
A        1, 2
B        1, 2, 1, 2
```

I want:

```
column1  column2
A        1, 2
B        1, 2
```

Here is my try:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    string Optional = "";

    foreach (var item in CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected))
    {
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planName", item.Text);

        foreach (var item1 in CheckBoxList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item1 => item1.Selected))
        {
            {
                Optional = Optional + item1.Text;
            }

        }
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionPlan", Optional);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before entering the inner loop reset the Optional variable to string.Empty

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{

    foreach (var item in CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected))
    {
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planName", item.Text);

        // If you don't reset the Optional here the next loop on CheckBoxList1 add
        // to the current value of Optional giving an invelid string
        string Optional = "";
        foreach (var item1 in CheckBoxList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item1 => item1.Selected))
        {
                Optional = Optional + item1.Text;
        }
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optionPlan", Optional);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```